# Sequelize findAll and Join table

Tags: mysql, join, sequelize.js

I want to do a simple chat app and my tables are like this (I don't know if it's the proper way to implement it):

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
userName: DataTypes.STRING,
email: DataTypes.STRING,
password: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Friend);
  }
}
```

Friends:

```
var Friend = sequelize.define('Friend', {
realId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
invitStatus: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    Friend.hasMany(models.Message);
  }
```

Messages:

```
var Message = sequelize.define('Message', {
text: DataTypes.TEXT,
sentBy: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
}
```

This is my current query:

```
models.User.findAll({
        where: {
            id: req.payload.userId
        },
        include: [{
            model: models.Friend,
            include: [{
                model: models.Message,
                order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
                limit: 1
            }]
        }]

    }).then(function(result) {
            reply(result).code(200);
        })
    }
```

Everything is working fine, except that I want to tell sequelize to get the Friend data from the User table with the realId from the Friend table.
Should I use the keyword "through"? I didn't get exactly how it works even though I read the docs multiple times. I'm a beginner in SQL.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: My current output is:

```
{
"id": 2,
"userName": "user2",
"email": "user2@example.com",
"password": "123456",
"createdAt": "2016-05-26T16:28:02.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2016-05-26T16:28:13.000Z",
"Friends": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "realId": 1,
    "invitStatus": "accepted",
    "createdAt": "2016-05-26T16:30:15.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-05-26T16:30:15.000Z",
    "UserId": 2,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "id": 18,
        "text": "ok",
        "sentBy": 1,
        "createdAt": "2016-05-26T16:59:36.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-05-26T16:59:36.000Z",
        "FriendId": 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

What I want is to add the value "userName", "email" and "password" to the Friends array by getting it from the User table with the "Friend.realId = User.id.

Comment: what is condition on which join happend?please elaborate it more about constraints on friend and message table

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm not sure what you exactly want to know but I edited my answer to make it more clear.Also sequelize created automatically in the Friends table a field "UserId" to link User and Friends table and it created a "FriendId" to link Friend and Message table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to clearly understand your problem. I assume that Friends is linked to User by `realId` so you shouldn't have a Friends model but only one User model.

If this answer can help anyone, in this case you should probably use **self-association**.

You can achive self-association between User and User (as friend) with something like

```
User.belongsToMany(models.User, { as: 'friends', foreignKey: 'userId', through: 'User_Friends' });
```

And if your User_Friends model need additional attributes you can specified them like below, else this join table will be automatically created.

```
var User_Friends = sequelize.define('User_Friends', {
    // ...
    invitStatus: DataTypes.STRING
    // ...
}
```